# HTML Input Pattern Guide or Answer

Tags: html, css

I am wondering where i could find a Generator for HTML Input Patterns, or a good guide for them.
If you feel like helping even more, im trying to find a pattern that makes sure that a @ is entered.
Thanks alot!
'#' = Information I don't want people seeing (Website name etc.)
P.S (I am wondering because I cannot find any good guides on using them, or how to actually figure out what to put in...)

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <input type="text" class="form" placeholder="Name" name="name"><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="form" placeholder="Email" name="email" pattern=''>
  <input value="@#" class="form" placeholder='@#'  name="type" readonly><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="form" placeholder="Backup Email" name="b_email" pattern=''><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="form" placeholder=Username name="username"><br><br>
  <input type="password" class="form" placeholder="Password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="password" class="form" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password_con"><br><br>
  <button class="form">Create</button>
</form><br><br>
```

All I know so far is

Comment: you should try a little bit harder, come up with at least a couple of things and then seek help. good luck

Comment: I've already found out how to make sure @ Isn't alloud, im just looking how to make sure that a @ is entered Pattern.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you say "I've already found out how to make sure @ Isn't allowed" then *include that code*! Show us as much as you've done, even if it lacks the required functionality. Include all the code you can, it makes it clearer that you have tried something and what direction you are heading in. Good luck.

Comment: @samiles Done!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp), which is literally one of the first results for `html pattern` has plenty of live examples.

```
<input type="text" name="type" pattern="[@]+" title="Must have an @ symbol">
```

In general though, these patterns use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) which is a completely separate subject you need to read up on.